# How to use TikZ to draw array of decorative boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I use TikZ to draw a picture like this one
[image]

---

I tried the following example but was unable to know how to draw cell outlines (borders).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1}%

\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}
        \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{red!\PercentColor!black}{}
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{12}{R}}
0.03 & 0.34 & 0.41 & 0.25 & 0.89 & 0.49 & 0.79 & 0.83 & 0.82 & 0.94 & 0.34 & 0.41 \\
0.49 & 0.25 & 0.80 & 0.83 & 0.93 & 0.25 & 0.82 & 0.80 & 0.35 & 0.00 & 0.25 & 0.80 \\
0.21 & 0.13 & 0.53 & 0.07 & 1.00 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.18 & 0.73 & 0.05 & 0.13 & 0.53 \\
0.81 & 0.49 & 0.27 & 0.07 & 0.57 & 0.12 & 0.26 & 0.39 & 0.57 & 0.80 & 0.49 & 0.27 \\
0.23 & 0.31 & 0.90 & 0.03 & 0.18 & 0.60 & 0.49 & 0.02 & 0.44 & 0.50 & 0.31 & 0.90 \\
0.40 & 0.91 & 0.84 & 0.88 & 0.04 & 0.59 & 0.75 & 0.91 & 0.69 & 0.88 & 0.91 & 0.84 \\
0.36 & 0.12 & 0.92 & 0.73 & 0.12 & 0.58 & 0.42 & 0.89 & 0.15 & 0.50 & 0.12 & 0.92 \\
0.93 & 0.07 & 0.57 & 0.43 & 0.12 & 0.70 & 0.54 & 0.25 & 0.06 & 0.57 & 0.07 & 0.57 \\
0.09 & 0.98 & 0.46 & 0.83 & 0.69 & 0.56 & 0.08 & 0.77 & 0.40 & 0.88 & 0.98 & 0.46 \\
0.81 & 0.49 & 0.27 & 0.07 & 0.57 & 0.12 & 0.26 & 0.39 & 0.57 & 0.80 & 0.49 & 0.27 \\
0.36 & 0.12 & 0.92 & 0.73 & 0.12 & 0.58 & 0.42 & 0.89 & 0.15 & 0.50 & 0.12 & 0.92 \\
0.93 & 0.07 & 0.57 & 0.43 & 0.12 & 0.70 & 0.54 & 0.25 & 0.06 & 0.57 & 0.07 & 0.57 \\
0.09 & 0.98 & 0.46 & 0.83 & 0.69 & 0.56 & 0.08 & 0.77 & 0.40 & 0.88 & 0.98 & 0.46 \\
0.81 & 0.49 & 0.27 & 0.07 & 0.57 & 0.12 & 0.26 & 0.39 & 0.57 & 0.80 & 0.49 & 0.27 \\
0.09 & 0.98 & 0.46 & 0.83 & 0.69 & 0.56 & 0.08 & 0.77 & 0.40 & 0.88 & 0.98 & 0.46 \\
0.07 & 0.44 & 0.65 & 0.46 & 0.65 & 0.75 & 0.80 & 0.56 & 0.89 & 0.50 & 0.44 & 0.65 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to replicate the exact color pattern here, or do you just want something that approximates it? Additionally, questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result would be greatly improved with an MWE. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. I do not care for the exact colors. Any color that  approximates it will be helpful as i can change the colors later using any color dropper. I will try to use the MWE but I am a beginner in latex and this may take some time.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 9):

I'd use a TikZ `matrix` to draw this.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
  nodes={inner sep=20pt,draw={green!20!yellow},line width=2pt},
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  ]{
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&&&\\
  };
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,12} \foreach \j in {1,...,12}{
    \pgfmathrandominteger\x{10}{70}
    \node[fill=black!\x!white,inner sep=20pt]at(m-\i-\j){};
  }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This uses the idea of Kevin C to put the colours but no `matrix`.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %% draw the color boxes
  \foreach \i in {0.5,...,11.5} {
  \foreach \j in {0.5,...,11.5}{
    \pgfmathrandominteger\x{10}{70}
    \node[fill=black!\x!white,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm]at(\i,\j){};
  }
  }
  %% draw the borders
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,12}{
    \draw[green!20!yellow,line width=2pt] (\x,0) -- (\x,12);
    }
  \foreach \y in {0,1,...,12}{
    \draw[green!20!yellow,line width=2pt] (0,\y) -- (12,\y);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Key strokes could have been further reduced, but I left it as is.

## Engage crystal ball:

Taking the code from OP (posted as an answer), One has to add vertical lines as `\begin{tabular}{|*{12}{R|}}` and horizontal lines through `\hline`s. F change the color of the lines, load `colortbl` and issue `\arrayrulecolor{green}`. I have also changed the `\fboxsep` to `8mm` so that things don;t go out of page. For `table`s I always prefer `\centering` over `\begin{center}`.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=0cm,right=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell,colortbl}

\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0}%
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1}%

\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{100.0*(#1-\MinNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MinNumber)}
        \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{red!\PercentColor!black}{}
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{8mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\arrayrulecolor{green}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{12}{R|}}\hline
0.03 & 0.34 & 0.41 & 0.25 & 0.89 & 0.49 & 0.79 & 0.83 & 0.82 & 0.94 & 0.34 & 0.41 \\\hline
0.49 & 0.25 & 0.80 & 0.83 & 0.93 & 0.25 & 0.82 & 0.80 & 0.35 & 0.00 & 0.25 & 0.80 \\\hline
0.21 & 0.13 & 0.53 & 0.07 & 1.00 & 0.66 & 0.07 & 0.18 & 0.73 & 0.05 & 0.13 & 0.53 \\\hline
0.81 & 0.49 & 0.27 & 0.07 & 0.57 & 0.12 & 0.26 & 0.39 & 0.57 & 0.80 & 0.49 & 0.27 \\\hline
0.23 & 0.31 & 0.90 & 0.03 & 0.18 & 0.60 & 0.49 & 0.02 & 0.44 & 0.50 & 0.31 & 0.90 \\\hline
0.40 & 0.91 & 0.84 & 0.88 & 0.04 & 0.59 & 0.75 & 0.91 & 0.69 & 0.88 & 0.91 & 0.84 \\\hline
0.36 & 0.12 & 0.92 & 0.73 & 0.12 & 0.58 & 0.42 & 0.89 & 0.15 & 0.50 & 0.12 & 0.92 \\\hline
0.93 & 0.07 & 0.57 & 0.43 & 0.12 & 0.70 & 0.54 & 0.25 & 0.06 & 0.57 & 0.07 & 0.57 \\\hline
0.09 & 0.98 & 0.46 & 0.83 & 0.69 & 0.56 & 0.08 & 0.77 & 0.40 & 0.88 & 0.98 & 0.46 \\\hline
0.81 & 0.49 & 0.27 & 0.07 & 0.57 & 0.12 & 0.26 & 0.39 & 0.57 & 0.80 & 0.49 & 0.27 \\\hline
0.36 & 0.12 & 0.92 & 0.73 & 0.12 & 0.58 & 0.42 & 0.89 & 0.15 & 0.50 & 0.12 & 0.92 \\\hline
0.93 & 0.07 & 0.57 & 0.43 & 0.12 & 0.70 & 0.54 & 0.25 & 0.06 & 0.57 & 0.07 & 0.57 \\\hline
0.09 & 0.98 & 0.46 & 0.83 & 0.69 & 0.56 & 0.08 & 0.77 & 0.40 & 0.88 & 0.98 & 0.46 \\\hline
0.81 & 0.49 & 0.27 & 0.07 & 0.57 & 0.12 & 0.26 & 0.39 & 0.57 & 0.80 & 0.49 & 0.27 \\\hline
0.09 & 0.98 & 0.46 & 0.83 & 0.69 & 0.56 & 0.08 & 0.77 & 0.40 & 0.88 & 0.98 & 0.46 \\\hline
0.07 & 0.44 & 0.65 & 0.46 & 0.65 & 0.75 & 0.80 & 0.56 & 0.89 & 0.50 & 0.44 & 0.65 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the exact requirements, the following may suffice:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz\foreach \i in {0,...,9}
  \foreach \j [evaluate={\k=rnd*75;}] in {0,...,9}
    \filldraw [fill=gray!\k, draw=green!50!brown, ultra thick]
      (\j,\i) rectangle +(1, 1);
\end{document}
```

[image]